# How to change column names while in a loop in R?

Tags: r

```
for(i in 1:3){
  
  names <- c("n1","n2","n3")
  assign(paste0("mydf",i), data.frame(matrix("", nrow = 3, ncol = 3)))
  
}
```

I tried the code shown below but it didn't work.

```
for(i in 1:3){
  
  names <- c("n1","n2","n3")
  assign(paste0("mydf",i), names(data.frame(matrix("", nrow = 3, ncol = 3)))[1:3] <- names)
  
}
```

What's your solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `colnames(df) <- names`, while using `names` as vector name might be confusing because function `names()` also exists and is used in your code

Comment: Please, please, please forget that `assign` exists and just put your data.frames in a list. Everything will be so much easier for you then.

Comment: @Waldi I get target of assignment expands to non-language object error.

Comment: check that `class(df)` is `data.frame` and `class(names)` is `character`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the approach I would take. The following script not only changes the column names, but also creates 3 dataframes in the global environment kind of like your original script.

```
for (i in 1:3){
  noms <- c("n1","n2","n3") # create the names in order the columns appear in the dataframe
  
  df_ <- data.frame(matrix("", nrow = 3, ncol = 3)) # create the dataframe
  
  df_nom <- paste("mydf", i, sep = "") # create the dataframe name
  
  colnames(df_) <- noms # assign the names to the columns
  
  assign(df_nom, df_) # rename the dataframe
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Normally one puts the data frames in a list but if you really want to them into the current environment then do the following.  If you want the global environment then replace the first line with `e <- .GlobalEnv` or if you want to create a list instead (preferable) then use `e <- list()` instead.

```
# define 3 data frames
e <- environment()  # or e <- .GlobalEnv or e <- list()
nms <- paste0("mydf", 1:3)
for(nm in nms) e[[nm]] <- data.frame(matrix("", 3, 3))

# change their column names
for(nm in nms) names(e[[nm]]) <- c("n1", "n2", "n3")
```

**2)** Even better if we want lists is:

```
L <- Map(function(x) data.frame(matrix("", 3, 3)), paste0("mydf", 1:3))
L[] <- lapply(L, `names<-`, c("n1", "n2", "n3"))  # change col names
```

### Converting

Note that we can convert a list L to data frames that are loose in the  environment using one of these depending on which environment you want to put the list components into.

```
list2env(L, environment())
list2env(L, .GlobalEnv)
```

and we can go the other way using where e is `environment()` or `.GlobalEnv` depending on what we need.  We can omit the e argument is the data frames are in the current environment.

```
L <- mget(nms, e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get` to get the `data.frame` by *name*, update the `names` and `assign` it back.

```
nNames <- c("n1","n2","n3")
for(i in 1:3) {
  D <- paste0("mydf",i)
  tt <- get(D)
  names(tt) <- nNames
  assign(D, tt)
}
names(mydf1)
#[1] "n1" "n2" "n3"
```

Alternatively the names could already be set when creating the `matrix` by using `dimnames`:

```
nNames <- c("n1","n2","n3")
for(i in 1:3) {
    assign(paste0("mydf", i),
           data.frame(matrix("", 3, 3, dimnames=list(NULL, nNames))))
}
names(mydf1)
#[1] "n1" "n2" "n3"
```